# Fabric UI component not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint

I have created a bottom placeholder which contains a Callout component.

The components look and work right in Chrome and FF but it doesn't even render in IE nor Edge:

This is how looks in chrome and ff: 
[FF - Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IapRx.png)

And this is what IE shows (both edge and ie 11):
[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YUiF.png)

In the console, I can see that the component is not even rendered to the HTML. The div ms-textAlignCenter should contain the component:
[IE DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsLps.png)

What is happening?

The code is this:

```
<div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12 ms-md4 ms-lg3">
    <div className="ms-textAlignCenter" ref={this._menuButtonElement}>
        {this.state.current != null ?
            <span id="toggleCallout" className={styles.buttonCallout} onClick={this._onShowMenuClicked}>
                <img src={this.state.current.icon}></img> {this.state.current.name}
                <span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDownMed verChevronIcon"></span>
            </span>
            : null
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Best regards

Americo

Comment: how do you update the current state?

Comment: I found that the component loads in pages that are not connected to hub sites. I got a script that removes the hub site menu in these pages since it seems to be a bug in IE but I get the same result. The person that shared the script hade the same problem and it was solve with the script but for me is not working. I added the script in the componenDidMount.